# Template Inheritance in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have declared `master.blade.php` as parent layout and homepage.blade.php extends it. But in Chrome and Microsoft Edge it is wrapped in an `iframe`.

This is `master.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>@yield('title', 'URL Shortner with Safe Browsing')</title>

    @section('headerScripts')
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    @show
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')

@section('footerScripts')
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@show
</body>
</html>
```

And this is `homepage.blade.php`.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'URL Shortner with Safe Browsing | Home Page')
@section('headerScripts')
    @parent
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/cover.css') }}" />
    <script src="{{ asset('js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js') }}" />

@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="site-wrapper">

        <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

            <div class="cover-container">

                <div class="masthead clearfix">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inner cover">
                    <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
                    <p class="lead">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="mastfoot">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
@section('footerScripts')
    @parent

@endsection
```

This is the output I see in the browser.

[image]

By checking in the Developer console, I can see there is `iframe` wrapper.

[image]

Never encountered such thing. Any suggestions. I may be doing something wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far i can see, it is not related to laravel. It seems a plugin or browser extension cause that problem. Try to deactivate all browser extensions, remove any js plugin on your code and look at your console for errors. You can check network tab for loaded javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but this is not a Laravel issue. I had this iframe problem before in Chrome, it was the `Avira Browser Safety` extension.

There are many other extensions that could cause such an issue. You can find out which one is it by looking at the source of the iframe. `src="chrome-extension://{id-of-the-extension}"`.

If you enable the developer mode in `chrome://extensions`, you will see the extension ids and should be able to search through the list and disable the one that is causing this.

The same goes for Microsoft Edge, just have a look around in the extensions section.